# wpf binding brush color

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties, brush

I have a custom textblock that has various text properties for left, right and same text as dependency properties. I use "Run" for making them have different foreground colors. It was like this in a method inside the control:

Inlines.Add(new Run(_leftValue[i]) { Foreground = Brushes.Red });

I added a dependency property for brush. How can I set it in my custom control's cs file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given us precious little to go on, but I'll give you an answer anyway. The format for setting a dependency proeprty is this:

```
[instance of the dependency object].SetValue(YourDependencyObject.TheDependencyProperty, value);
```

so for the example of a DP taking a brush, this should so it:

```
this.SetValue(MyCustomControl.ForegroundBrush, Brushes.Red);
```

Note that `MyCustomControl` is the literal name of your type, and `this` should be castable to a DependencyObject (if your control derives from Window, Control, FrameworkElement, etc. then it derives from DependencyObject).

Comment: I'm sorry about not explaning properly. I will try your solution.